# Show $I\Vdash_{\Sigma} φ$ iff $I\Vdash_{\Sigma} \forall x φ$.

Tags: first-order-logic, satisfiability

Let $\Sigma$ be a signature (decidable, with equality) and $I$ an interpretation structure over said signature. Let $φ$ be a formula. Show $I\Vdash_{\Sigma} φ$ iff $I\Vdash_{\Sigma} \forall x φ$.


This is an exercise in the book *Foundations of Logic and Theory of Computation* by Amílcar Sernadas.  I want this to show that $(\forall x \,\varphi )\models \varphi$ .

**[For clarification]**
We define $I\Vdash \varphi$ in the following way:
[image]

Comment: Should your "$\Vdash$"s be "$\models$"s? (Annoyingly, "$\Vdash$," "$\vdash$," and "$\models$" mean three varyingly different things.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber honestly I'm honestly not sure, in this book, in the book I'm following and in the one I referred to, the definition uses this one. We use $\models$ when we have satisfaction for every interpretation structure.

Comment: This is usually called closure theorem in some books. To strictly prove your case in your book you need to invoke the axioms and rules specifically allowed in your book, most likely UG. Intuitively this is obvious from your above quoted definition of satisfaction of a wff with free variables...